# Do Dr. Octopus' arms continue to work after he dies?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, artificial-intelligence

Dr Octopus' robotic arms are generally portrayed as having their own intelligence. Have they ever been shown to operate after Dr. Octopus has died?

Comic continuities are preferred, but any are ok.

Comment: I could have sworn I saw a panel where the arms were just carrying his body along for the ride, but I can't place it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only instance I am aware is in *Civil War - Secret Wars* #3. Otto Octavius' arms were ripped out of him and given to The Kingpin. They killed him and continued functioning on the rotting corpse. Thus his arms were still "alive", and would presumably work the same way if on Dr. Octopus when he died.

[image: Civil War King Ock]

Comment: Welcome to Sci-fi Stack Exchange! I've gone ahead and done the legwork to add a screenshot (Marvel Unlimited is wonderful!) and corrected it to say that it was The Kingpin, not Otto Octavius. Hope to see you contribute more on this site.

Comment: I found another example in [*Spider-Man: Reign*](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_Reign_Vol_1_3) if you want to add that to your answer.